# How can I concatenate a value inside function in jquery in this situation?

Tags: php, jquery, concatenation

I want to concatenate a value inside function in jquery. See code below. I want to put value data 1 into a function. Do you have any way to achieve what I want? Appreciate.

```js
     var data='1';
 var user='<?php echo bp_core_get_user_domain('+ data +');?>';
    
         $("#find_members").html(user);
```

Comment: PHP isn't available on a page once it has loaded. It all process on the server and then the generated code is sent to the client. You'll need to send out an ajax request.

Comment: Ok. And what if I need aJax request with php code for eval()... ))

Comment: What is `eval()... ))`? Also, is Winston == conan? The ajax sends data from the client to a server side language then awaits the response that the server sends with the data requested. So you'd have this `<?php echo bp_core_get_user_domain($_POST['data']');?>` on a PHP page that this page would send the request to.

Comment: he is not me. I believe Winston has the same problem like me.

Comment: Okay, here's another posting about how this can be done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php

Comment: chris85, what do you suggest is that I should put <?php echo bp_core_get_user_domain($_POST['data']');?> in my search.php. I confuse.

Comment: you could achieve this using a hidden field mate and is this `data` variable always set to 1..??

Comment: I was wondering can I use ajax to call the php function bp_core_get_user_domain( ). Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Make an empty php page.

file.php

Inside put the PHP you want to interact with the JS value.

```
<?php 
function bp_core_get_user_domain($something) {
     //do Stuff here
      return $something;
}
echo bp_core_get_user_domain($_POST['data_var']);
?>
```

Then on your page make an ajax request to this script and the data will come back...

```
var data='1';
$.post( "file.php", { data_var: data})
  .done(function( data ) {
    $("#find_members").html(data);
  });
```

This is a rough version (untested), there are MANY examples out there for this.

Comment: Thank you for your time. The big issue here bp_core_get_user_domain() cannot be called in ajax. I don't know why. maybe it is buddypress function. firebug said NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error. The ajax has no problem if I put plaintext.

Comment: `bp_core_get_user_domain` is obviously a custom function which you will need to `include` inside the php code.

Comment: Can you guide me how to include it? it is a buddypress function, so I have to find the file inside buddypress and include it in my php, or do I have other way to include it?

Comment: Oh yeah, @EternalHour good point missed that one. @conan somewhere you have `function bp_core_get_user_domain($something) {...` you need to bring that over to the `file.php`. If that is defined in a config file you could just do `include 'config.php';`.

Comment: I have create a function to test. It doesn't work when I include any file in file.php. Do I have to do something? I think that is why bp_core_get_user_domain cannot be call in file.php, but can call in other php file.

Comment: Can you post your whole file or atleast the function and I can show you how to put it into 'file.php'?

Comment: I've made a sample function you can fill it in with what actually goes there.